# Can someone explain to me why python 3.4 is parsing a string to an int without me explicitly asking for it

Tags: python

I am so confused it's beyond belief, it's probably a noobie mistake, but I am thoroughly befuddled by this behavior. Here's the small algorithm (as I think it should be):

```
a, b, n = input().split()
x = 0

def prod(num):
    x=1
    for y in range(len(num)):
        if int(num[y])>0:
           x*=int(num[y])
    x+=int(num)
    return x

while x < int(n):
    a, b = b, prod(b)+prod(a)
    print(b, end=' ')
    x+=1
```

and here's how I apparently have to do it to make it work:

```
a, b, n = input().split()
x = 0

def prod(num):
    x=1
    for y in range(len(str(num))):
        if int(str(num)[y])>0:
           x*=int(str(num)[y])
    x+=int(num)
    return x

while x < int(n):
    a, b = b, prod(b)+prod(a)
    print(b, end=' ')
    x+=1
```

so if it isn't clear, my problem is in the prod function. it seems to convert the string to an int for no apparent reason.

the input I'm giving it is `1 100 3` and is supposed to be of that format.

Comment: just iterate over num directly, you don't need range

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Python is not implicitly turning your string into an integer, no. Instead, you are giving your function an integer.

You are returning an integer from `prod()` and in the next operation, you pass that integer to the `prod()` function.

The steps are:

1. `a, b, n = '1', '100', '3'`
2. call `prod('100') + prod('1')`, produces `101 + 2` is `3`, an integer.
3. `a, b = '100', 3`, so now `b` is an integer, go to the next iteration.
4. call `prod(3) + prod('100')`; you are passing in an integer to your function.

Perhaps you need to convert the sum to return a string from `prod()` instead? Change your return statement to:

```
return str(x)
```

or perhaps the sum of the `prod()` results should be a string:

```
a, b = b, str(prod(b) + prod(a))
```

You can simplify your function to just iterating over `num` directly, and use the fact that single characters have an order too:

```
def prod(num):
    x = 1
    for digit in num:
        if digit > '0':
           x *= int(digit)
    x += int(num)
    return x  # or `str(x) if a string is expected
```

Your `while` loop should just be a `for` loop with `range()`:

```
for iteration in range(int(n)):
    a, b = b, str(prod(b) + prod(a))
    print(b, end=' ')
```

Comment: oh so it's not converting anything, it's not an error in the first iteration. thank you so much this actually helps me understand python a lot better!

Comment: if I return a string I need to change prod(a)+prod(b) to int(prod(a))+int(prod(b)), honestly all of this seems a little unnecessary though I understand it completely.

however, is there maybe a way to iterate through the digits of an integer?

also thank you so much!

Comment: @user3204883: just return the integer then and use `str(prod(b) + prod(a))`. I already cover that in my answer now.

Comment: such an elegant solution, python <3